# How do you say “briefly, we exist” in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

Hoping to expand my Latin knowledge but for now, seeking help from the community. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just to be clear: Do you want to say "we exist for a short time" or "to put it briefly, we exist"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 6):

There's already a Latin phrase which encapsulates this idea: *ars longa, vita brevis*, "life is short but art is long (=lasts a long time)."

You could easily just quote the latter part and not only have it mean what you want, but also be recognizable.

So my suggestion: ***vita brevis***.